# Feeding Baby while Traveling

Tags: infant, food, travel

With a seven month old on a plane, it can be pretty hard to feed the baby without making a mess, but we have a long flight ahead of us in coach as part of holiday travels.  He is old enough to be wishing to feed himself, can do so with puffs and baby crackers and the like, but still eats pretty soft and juicy kinds of things otherwise, so he often winds up fairly sticky (**and so do those that are nearby**).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Bring wipes with you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you seen those silicone squeeze pouches for infant feeding? They are sized for baby hands and you can fill them with soft foods like applesauce or other purees or yogurt. They're basically a reusable alternative to the disposable squeeze pouches you can get at the grocery store and I like that you can fill it with homemade food and control the amount of sugar and eliminate preservatives & other additives. The one I'm thinking of (Silli Squeeze), baby has to squeeze the bottle/pouch while biting/gumming the spout to get the food out, so it is pretty spill proof.

I would recommend letting your baby practice with it a bit before the flight though so you don't end up with a hungry and frustrated baby on the plane :)

Answer (score 4):

Flights are a brief disruption to routine, so you can and should adjust your routines to accommodate them as well.  In other words, if baby can't eat soft and juicy things cleanly yet, then either serve only non-soft/juicy foods he can eat well, or feed him with a spoon.  Skipping one day of "learning how to eat" won't do any harm.

And oh, some unsolicited advice spoken with the gravelly voice of experience: keep one eye on the baby's hands while you're eating your own food as well, so his sticky little fingers don't upend a tray of pasta into your lap...

Comment: lol! about the upturned tray of pasta!!  Yes, even fed from a spoon tends to get sticky.  He likes to blow raspberries and immitate elephants and the whole bit.

Comment: Then you might want to just stick to bottle/breast for the flight.